# How to use ties argument of approx in R

Tags: r, interpolation, approximation

I have a vector of dates I want to interpolate to get the aproximated values, making a linear interpolation. I have a dataframe with known values with other dates, called "subset".
This is the "subset" dataframe of the values with the dates and the values.

```
> subset
                    TPMname      ActivityDesc TPM_ValorObjetivo TPM_ValorMinimo TPM_ValorMaximo Val_Registrado
    1  Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          16.49
    2  Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          16.68
    3  Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          16.94
    4  Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          16.73
    5  Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          16.99
    6  Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          18.00
    7  Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          18.12
    8  Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          17.50
    9  Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          17.07
    10 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          16.74
    11 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          17.10
    12 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          16.96
    13 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          16.50
    14 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          16.83
    15 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18           8.30
    16 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          17.26
    17 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          17.15
    18 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          17.02
    19 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          17.43
    20 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          17.25
    21 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          15.00
    22 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          16.60
    23 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          15.00
    24 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          17.15
    25 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          17.40
    26 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18           8.20
    27 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          17.10
    28 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          15.00
    29 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          17.07
    30 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          17.40
    31 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          15.00
    32 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          15.00
    33 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          16.60
    34 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          12.00
    35 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          17.10
    36 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          15.00
    37 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          15.00
    38 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          15.10
    39 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          15.00
    40 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          15.00
    41 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          15.00
    42 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          15.70
    43 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          16.20
    44 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          15.00
    45 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          15.00
    46 Arenadora AL100 (R4) Control arenadora                15            11.7              18          15.60
           Val_FechaCierre
    1  2022-05-24 09:38:00
    2  2022-05-17 13:21:00
    3  2022-05-09 12:23:00
    4  2022-05-02 13:05:00
    5  2022-04-25 08:51:00
    6  2022-04-19 12:10:00
    7  2022-04-19 12:10:00
    8  2022-04-05 13:44:00
    9  2022-03-28 08:29:00
    10 2022-03-21 09:08:00
    11 2022-03-14 13:56:00
    12 2022-03-07 08:02:00
    13 2022-02-28 09:21:00
    14 2022-02-21 09:50:00
    15 2022-02-21 09:23:00
    16 2022-02-14 10:12:00
    17 2022-02-07 13:42:00
    18 2022-01-31 09:27:00
    19 2022-01-24 09:59:00
    20 2022-01-17 10:52:00
    21 2021-10-04 17:27:00
    22 2021-09-27 12:30:00
    23 2021-09-20 12:16:00
    24 2021-09-13 10:41:00
    25 2021-09-06 23:14:00
    26 2021-09-06 23:13:00
    27 2021-08-30 16:06:00
    28 2021-08-23 19:23:00
    29 2021-08-16 12:48:00
    30 2021-08-10 10:50:00
    31 2021-08-02 23:27:00
    32 2021-07-26 17:59:00
    33 2021-07-19 11:18:00
    34 2021-07-12 15:48:00
    35 2021-07-05 12:06:00
    36 2021-06-28 19:50:00
    37 2021-06-22 07:42:00
    38 2021-06-14 11:31:00
    39 2021-06-07 15:50:00
    40 2021-05-31 13:11:00
    41 2021-05-17 11:36:00
    42 2021-05-10 13:41:00
    43 2021-05-03 12:56:00
    44 2021-02-12 08:50:00
    45 2020-12-09 09:06:00
    46 2020-11-30 12:48:00
```

This is the vector of dates I want to interpolate:

```
> tiemposr4primarios$h0
   [1] "2021-07-26 20:40:04 GMT" "2021-07-27 13:56:32 GMT" "2021-07-27 14:03:35 GMT" "2021-07-28 12:12:17 GMT" "2021-07-28 21:45:29 GMT"
   [6] "2021-07-29 12:43:48 GMT" "2021-07-29 14:57:44 GMT" "2021-07-29 21:35:48 GMT" "2021-07-30 13:17:23 GMT" "2021-07-30 14:32:36 GMT"
  [11] "2021-08-02 05:19:04 GMT" "2021-08-02 21:46:01 GMT" "2021-08-02 21:54:06 GMT" "2021-08-03 01:06:37 GMT" "2021-08-04 05:35:52 GMT"
  [16] "2021-08-04 14:12:03 GMT" "2021-08-04 21:12:17 GMT" "2021-08-04 21:28:51 GMT" "2021-08-05 01:19:07 GMT" "2021-08-05 04:20:39 GMT"
  [21] "2021-08-05 22:05:41 GMT" "2021-08-05 22:28:28 GMT" "2021-08-05 23:34:33 GMT" "2021-08-06 05:59:05 GMT" "2021-08-09 13:02:23 GMT"
  [26] "2021-08-10 07:37:35 GMT" "2021-08-10 07:49:38 GMT" "2021-08-10 12:39:13 GMT" "2021-08-10 14:59:54 GMT" "2021-08-10 22:31:36 GMT"
  [31] "2021-08-10 23:11:42 GMT" "2021-08-11 04:45:15 GMT" "2021-08-11 06:51:39 GMT" "2021-08-11 07:08:51 GMT" "2021-08-11 12:45:00 GMT"
  [36] "2021-08-11 15:51:36 GMT" "2021-08-11 21:01:06 GMT" "2021-08-11 21:41:30 GMT" "2021-08-11 22:25:30 GMT" "2021-08-12 02:33:02 GMT"
  [41] "2021-08-12 04:20:21 GMT" "2021-08-12 07:24:03 GMT" "2021-08-12 07:39:22 GMT" "2021-08-12 13:45:15 GMT" "2021-08-12 18:29:57 GMT"
  [46] "2021-08-13 01:35:08 GMT" "2021-08-13 03:31:23 GMT" "2021-08-16 05:48:32 GMT" "2021-08-16 07:13:19 GMT" "2021-08-16 07:20:27 GMT"
  [51] "2021-08-16 23:39:11 GMT" "2021-08-17 07:54:26 GMT" "2021-08-17 21:36:24 GMT" "2021-08-17 21:42:48 GMT" "2021-08-18 21:35:17 GMT"
  [56] "2021-08-19 04:13:47 GMT" "2021-08-19 22:13:08 GMT" "2021-08-20 01:22:01 GMT" "2021-08-23 13:34:23 GMT" "2021-08-23 15:38:40 GMT"
  [61] "2021-08-23 20:16:58 GMT" "2021-08-23 22:48:10 GMT" "2021-08-24 14:17:28 GMT" "2021-08-24 14:31:48 GMT" "2021-08-24 15:10:35 GMT"
  [66] "2021-08-24 15:35:02 GMT" "2021-08-24 20:43:34 GMT" "2021-08-25 17:33:44 GMT" "2021-08-25 22:25:41 GMT" "2021-08-25 23:48:07 GMT"
  [71] "2021-08-26 13:23:13 GMT" "2021-08-26 13:39:55 GMT" "2021-08-26 15:26:12 GMT" "2021-08-26 18:58:47 GMT" "2021-08-26 21:27:50 GMT"
  [76] "2021-08-27 01:07:12 GMT" "2021-08-27 04:45:54 GMT" "2021-08-30 05:38:03 GMT" "2021-08-30 12:30:33 GMT" "2021-08-30 19:00:23 GMT"
  [81] "2021-08-31 03:22:18 GMT" "2021-08-31 07:42:15 GMT" "2021-08-31 10:44:44 GMT" "2021-08-31 16:49:16 GMT" "2021-08-31 19:16:20 GMT"
  [86] "2021-08-31 21:04:58 GMT" "2021-09-01 02:31:12 GMT" "2021-09-01 04:37:43 GMT" "2021-09-01 16:12:09 GMT" "2021-09-01 20:38:53 GMT"
  [91] "2021-09-01 21:34:59 GMT" "2021-09-02 04:20:28 GMT" "2021-09-02 04:26:52 GMT" "2021-09-03 05:10:43 GMT" "2021-09-07 07:06:56 GMT"
  [96] "2021-09-07 07:29:14 GMT" "2021-09-07 09:48:56 GMT" "2021-09-07 10:09:01 GMT" "2021-09-08 07:22:09 GMT" "2021-09-08 07:36:21 GMT"
 [101] "2021-09-08 13:10:42 GMT" "2021-09-08 16:01:12 GMT" "2021-09-08 20:55:13 GMT" "2021-09-08 22:08:08 GMT" "2021-09-09 05:29:56 GMT"
 [106] "2021-09-09 21:51:34 GMT" "2021-09-10 04:20:20 GMT" "2021-09-10 06:37:06 GMT" "2021-09-10 09:34:06 GMT" "2021-09-10 11:48:19 GMT"
 [111] "2021-09-13 06:58:17 GMT" "2021-09-13 07:50:29 GMT" "2021-09-13 12:11:32 GMT" "2021-09-13 13:39:05 GMT" "2021-09-13 17:08:07 GMT"
 [116] "2021-09-13 20:33:54 GMT" "2021-09-14 01:08:50 GMT" "2021-09-14 04:30:29 GMT" "2021-09-14 07:23:28 GMT" "2021-09-14 12:30:09 GMT"
 [121] "2021-09-14 13:55:38 GMT" "2021-09-14 20:41:46 GMT" "2021-09-14 23:48:13 GMT" "2021-09-15 05:06:25 GMT" "2021-09-15 12:21:29 GMT"
 [126] "2021-09-15 13:32:27 GMT" "2021-09-15 14:04:00 GMT" "2021-09-15 16:58:08 GMT" "2021-09-15 22:09:41 GMT" "2021-09-16 02:23:06 GMT"
 [131] "2021-09-16 04:09:58 GMT" "2021-09-16 06:44:30 GMT" "2021-09-16 14:05:45 GMT" "2021-09-16 22:27:34 GMT" "2021-09-16 23:22:39 GMT"
 [136] "2021-09-17 06:31:05 GMT" "2021-09-17 09:20:52 GMT" "2021-09-21 06:35:40 GMT" "2021-09-21 06:43:52 GMT" "2021-09-21 08:05:04 GMT"
 [141] "2021-09-21 12:24:38 GMT" "2021-09-21 16:43:48 GMT" "2021-09-21 21:15:43 GMT" "2021-09-22 02:12:20 GMT" "2021-09-22 05:49:12 GMT"
 [146] "2021-09-22 13:17:10 GMT" "2021-09-22 15:20:47 GMT" "2021-09-22 15:47:32 GMT" "2021-09-23 10:59:12 GMT" "2021-09-23 11:14:10 GMT"
 [151] "2021-09-23 14:01:05 GMT" "2021-09-23 14:45:18 GMT" "2021-09-23 15:06:50 GMT" "2021-09-23 16:30:34 GMT" "2021-09-23 17:17:25 GMT"
 [156] "2021-09-23 20:11:37 GMT" "2021-09-23 21:43:31 GMT" "2021-09-24 04:24:16 GMT" "2021-09-24 05:40:49 GMT" "2021-09-24 06:46:28 GMT"
 [161] "2021-09-24 08:59:01 GMT" "2021-09-24 10:50:07 GMT" "2021-09-24 11:36:32 GMT" "2021-09-24 13:45:02 GMT" "2021-09-27 08:41:48 GMT"
 [166] "2021-09-27 10:07:38 GMT" "2021-09-27 13:14:08 GMT" "2021-09-27 18:06:15 GMT" "2021-09-27 23:05:20 GMT" "2021-09-27 23:19:27 GMT"
 [171] "2021-09-28 04:50:31 GMT" "2021-09-28 07:40:57 GMT" "2021-09-28 12:38:03 GMT" "2021-09-28 21:46:11 GMT" "2021-09-28 21:59:10 GMT"
 [176] "2021-09-29 05:24:42 GMT" "2021-09-29 06:48:00 GMT" "2021-09-29 09:52:09 GMT" "2021-09-29 12:16:34 GMT" "2021-09-29 13:51:58 GMT"
 [181] "2021-09-29 21:03:47 GMT" "2021-09-29 23:30:02 GMT" "2021-09-30 04:16:20 GMT" "2021-09-30 07:08:46 GMT" "2021-09-30 09:56:59 GMT"
```

The dates of the subset dataframe are ordered so I want that when a tie of dates occurs, to take the first date to interpolate if the desired date is less that the tied dates, and to take the last date if the desired date is bigger that the tied dates.

I read about the "ties" argument taking ordered values if the dates are in order when a tie happens. So, I tried the following code, and I get all NAs for y:

```
    > data.frame(approx(subset$Val_FechaCierre,subset$Val_Registrado,xout=tiemposr4primarios$h0,ties="ordered"))
                      x  y
1   2021-07-26 20:40:04 NA
2   2021-07-27 13:56:32 NA
3   2021-07-27 14:03:35 NA
4   2021-07-28 12:12:17 NA
5   2021-07-28 21:45:29 NA
6   2021-07-29 12:43:48 NA
7   2021-07-29 14:57:44 NA
8   2021-07-29 21:35:48 NA
9   2021-07-30 13:17:23 NA
10  2021-07-30 14:32:36 NA
11  2021-08-02 05:19:04 NA
12  2021-08-02 21:46:01 NA
13  2021-08-02 21:54:06 NA
14  2021-08-03 01:06:37 NA
15  2021-08-04 05:35:52 NA
16  2021-08-04 14:12:03 NA
17  2021-08-04 21:12:17 NA
18  2021-08-04 21:28:51 NA
19  2021-08-05 01:19:07 NA
20  2021-08-05 04:20:39 NA
21  2021-08-05 22:05:41 NA
22  2021-08-05 22:28:28 NA
23  2021-08-05 23:34:33 NA
24  2021-08-06 05:59:05 NA
25  2021-08-09 13:02:23 NA
26  2021-08-10 07:37:35 NA
27  2021-08-10 07:49:38 NA
28  2021-08-10 12:39:13 NA
29  2021-08-10 14:59:54 NA
30  2021-08-10 22:31:36 NA
31  2021-08-10 23:11:42 NA
32  2021-08-11 04:45:15 NA
33  2021-08-11 06:51:39 NA
34  2021-08-11 07:08:51 NA
35  2021-08-11 12:45:00 NA
36  2021-08-11 15:51:36 NA
37  2021-08-11 21:01:06 NA
38  2021-08-11 21:41:30 NA
39  2021-08-11 22:25:30 NA
40  2021-08-12 02:33:02 NA
41  2021-08-12 04:20:21 NA
42  2021-08-12 07:24:03 NA
43  2021-08-12 07:39:22 NA
44  2021-08-12 13:45:15 NA
45  2021-08-12 18:29:57 NA
46  2021-08-13 01:35:08 NA
47  2021-08-13 03:31:23 NA
48  2021-08-16 05:48:32 NA
49  2021-08-16 07:13:19 NA
50  2021-08-16 07:20:27 NA
51  2021-08-16 23:39:11 NA
52  2021-08-17 07:54:26 NA
53  2021-08-17 21:36:24 NA
54  2021-08-17 21:42:48 NA
55  2021-08-18 21:35:17 NA
56  2021-08-19 04:13:47 NA
57  2021-08-19 22:13:08 NA
58  2021-08-20 01:22:01 NA
59  2021-08-23 13:34:23 NA
60  2021-08-23 15:38:40 NA
61  2021-08-23 20:16:58 NA
62  2021-08-23 22:48:10 NA
63  2021-08-24 14:17:28 NA
64  2021-08-24 14:31:48 NA
65  2021-08-24 15:10:35 NA
66  2021-08-24 15:35:02 NA
67  2021-08-24 20:43:34 NA
68  2021-08-25 17:33:44 NA
69  2021-08-25 22:25:41 NA
70  2021-08-25 23:48:07 NA
71  2021-08-26 13:23:13 NA
72  2021-08-26 13:39:55 NA
73  2021-08-26 15:26:12 NA
74  2021-08-26 18:58:47 NA
75  2021-08-26 21:27:50 NA
76  2021-08-27 01:07:12 NA
77  2021-08-27 04:45:54 NA
78  2021-08-30 05:38:03 NA
79  2021-08-30 12:30:33 NA
80  2021-08-30 19:00:23 NA
81  2021-08-31 03:22:18 NA
82  2021-08-31 07:42:15 NA
83  2021-08-31 10:44:44 NA
84  2021-08-31 16:49:16 NA
85  2021-08-31 19:16:20 NA
86  2021-08-31 21:04:58 NA
87  2021-09-01 02:31:12 NA
88  2021-09-01 04:37:43 NA
89  2021-09-01 16:12:09 NA
90  2021-09-01 20:38:53 NA
91  2021-09-01 21:34:59 NA
92  2021-09-02 04:20:28 NA
93  2021-09-02 04:26:52 NA
94  2021-09-03 05:10:43 NA
95  2021-09-07 07:06:56 NA
96  2021-09-07 07:29:14 NA
97  2021-09-07 09:48:56 NA
98  2021-09-07 10:09:01 NA
99  2021-09-08 07:22:09 NA
100 2021-09-08 07:36:21 NA
```

If I use ties=mean i get a working result, but doesn't work for me as i need to interpolate between two values.

I also tried ties = list("ordered", mean) without success.

Comment: Which data type do you use for the timestamps? It looks as though they are strings, which cannot work.

Comment: I don't thinks that's the problem. I previously converted the timestapms to data format, and approx works with ties=mean, but that's not the result I want. This is what works: `> data.frame(approx(subset$Val_FechaCierre,subset$Val_Registrado,xout=tiemposr4primarios$h0,ties=mean))`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

Ties argument didn't work beacuse the date columns were not in order.

So i ordered the with the Order() function and it worked (it has to be ordered in increasing order).